# Visual Studio and XML Commenting in Javascript makes "public" methods disappear in intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, xml-comments

I was elated to find out that I could use XML commenting in my javascript (i.e.):

```
/// <summary>Determines the area of a circle based on a radius parameter.</summary>
/// <param name="Name" type="String">Give this dude a NAME!</param>
/// <returns type="Nothing">The area.</returns>
```

That was until I realized that after I did this, my "public" methods were no longer listed in intellisense... :-(

```
 this.greet = function (greeting) {
        alert(greeting + " " + this);
    }
```

The above would show up when I would instantiate var thePlayer = new player('bob'); ... thePlayer. <-- greet would be listed, UNTIL I threw in the above XML comments.

Does anyone have any experience with this and a work around?  Being able to comment javascript into intellisense would be very nice!

Comment: Did you try commenting with *'s or just using two dashes instead of three/

Comment: I added the asterisks HERE so the summary, param and returns tags would show up. These are the three that MS uses for the commenting.  Also, 3 slashes so that VS would see that I am attempting XML commenting.

Comment: I'm assuming you only added the asterisks because you hadn't indented the comments (thus getting syntax highlighting) -- my edit should fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you remove the (type="Nothing") from the returns it should show the members on a player.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks a ton!  This is NOW cool again!  Guess you can BREAK stuff even using XML commenting.  Thanks!